# NXT brick output ports not working properly

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming, motor

My NXT brick will not let motors run.  When I download a program the motor will move forward and backward and then stop - sort of a wiggle.  Another motor will not work at all.  This happens for all three ports.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Does this happen for all the motors you have? The problem could be there. I've had a motor which only ran in one direction (it did kind of get tortured before that, admittedly), for example. In any case, the customer service should be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting a Wait block after the motor block. Set it to wait for 5 seconds.

I think your program just terminates after one block. Please post your program next time you have a mindstorms question.